# Goto Function definition in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, perl, keyboard-shortcuts

If my cursor is in a function call in a perl file , is there any shortcut in eclipse that would take me to the definition of the function( in the same file) like `gd` in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hover over function name, which should turn to a hyperlink pointing to its definition.

Answer (score 1):

@others who could have been looking for this feature:

Once you jump to the function definition (or any other place) in Eclipse, you can go back to the previous location by using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> for  Navigate->back.

Comment: In general I think that we should all consult `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `L` from time to time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only the keyboard, press <kbd>F3</kbd>.